# how decreasing ground fault resistance decrease the touched voltage?

Tags: power-supply, electromagnetic, fault

Fault current = supply voltage / fault path R.

Assume live conductor of 230v touches the equipment metal frame.

1) assume R path through grounding electrode 25 ohm

I= 230/25=9.2A

2) R=3 ohm

I=76.6 A

3) assume i have conductor for fault path 0.5 ohm
I=460A

if in any case of the which -above v =I*R=230V !! because both I and R changed so voltage is the same ..in ideal sc v=0 and R=0 ,so here can i say this calculated current before sc occurred but after occurring V is decreased with R ?

i want to know the voltage values  on the equipment in each case,and consequently the voltage on my hand during touching this equipment ?

Comment: This question is very confusing as it is posted.

Comment: Still confusing after edits.

Comment: Some proper capitalisation of sentences and words would help legibility. If English is not your first language then please add this to your user profile and we will help you fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5ePPs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Very simple equivalent circuit.*

> if in any case of the which -above v =I*R=230V !! because both I and R changed so voltage is the same ..in ideal sc v=0 and R=0 ,so here can i say this calculated current before sc occurred but after occurring V is decreased with R?

I don't know what that means but you don't seem to be taking into account that there is other resistance in the line to your faulty equipment. These will reduce the voltage at the fault and limit the current a little.

> i (sic) want to know the voltage values on the equipment in each case,and consequently the voltage on my hand during touching this equipment ?

To calculate the voltages in each case you need to have each of the resistance values above. You also need the ground voltage. This is quite a bit of work.

50 mA is enough to kill and you can get that much current at much lower voltages than 230 V. **Do not experiment or mess around by touching live equipment.**

Comment: Thank you- assume the resistance mentioned in the question is the full path R grid+house+cable..i know that less R means Higher fault current then faster clearing by CB but i read also less resistance means less voltage on the faulted equipment chassis and i don't understand this point  ,assume only R from Eq to the utility Neutral is changing from  25 to 3 to 0.5 ohm ,is the voltage on the Eq chassis will be the same in all cases ?

Comment: The circuit is a simple resistor voltage divider. If R EARTH gets smaller then V on the red box gets smaller.

Comment: ok i got it ,voltage drop in R grid+R cable is the crises here ,when fault path from the Equipment to the utility increased ;Fault current will decreased ,voltage drop will decreased ,so that higher percentage of source voltage will appear on the Equipment ,isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it. Why are you asking this question?

Comment: to know how much would be dangerous or degree of hazardous when touching the equipment or the EGC or the grounding electrode conductor during instance of a grounding fault ,I read in NEC voltage will be so dangerous from 60AC and above .. i know danger is depending upon R of body beside  Touch voltage so any value of V may be dangerous , but my problem was to understand the question above, line have 230 v directly touching an Equipment so at any case this equipment chassis voltage have to be 230 V ,but i missed the point you mentioned the resistance from grid to the eq will make adequate drop

Comment: "*... will make adequate drop*" sounds as though you think that this somehow will be safe. It will not be safe. The voltage could be close to 230 V.

Comment: no i don't mean it will be safe
i mean it depending on R of grounding system for example Rgrid=2 ohm,Rcable =0.1ohm,R grounding=0.5ohm, so If=88.5A-Voltage on Equipment=230-88.5*2.1=44V it is less than 60 so it is acceptable but not safe

Comment: R GRID will be low. e.g. My house has a 63 A supply. If the voltage is to remain at 230 +/- 5% then max voltage drop at 63 A will be 11.5 V. \$ R_{GRID} = \frac {11.5}{63} = 0.18 \ \Omega \$.

Comment: ok values depend on distance between source and service Disconnecting means to Equipment ,the important point here i got  and i saw how voltage on Equipment can change with ground fault path Resistance e.g. at R=25 not like when R=1 ohm ..